# How to pass test data for classification model if independent variables are categorical in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I am building a classification model for a data set containing independent variables as categorical values. As `fit()` is not supported for non-numeric values, I need to apply either `LabelEncoder` or `OneHotEncoder`.

My data set looks like this:

| index | outlook | temperature | humidity | windy | play |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | sunny | hot | high | false | no |
| 1 | sunny | hot | high | true | no |
| 2 | overcast | hot | high | false | yes |
| 3 | rainy | mild | high | false | yes |
| 4 | rainy | cool | normal | false | yes |
| 5 | rainy | cool | normal | true | no |

My code is as follows:

```
w = pd.read_csv("/content/drive/MyDrive/weather.csv")

from sklearn import preprocessing
lencoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    
w['humidity'] = lencoder.fit_transform(w['humidity'])
w['outlook'] = lencoder.fit_transform(w['outlook'])
w['temperature'] = lencoder.fit_transform(w['temperature'])
w['windy'] = lencoder.fit_transform(w['windy'])

x = w.iloc[:, :4].values
y = w.iloc[:, -1].values
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = model_selection.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.1)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

How can I now predict an individual test sample such as `[sunny, hot, high, false]`?

Comment: I think this may help you: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/56331/prediction-after-one-hot-encoding

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode it with same values that the LabelEncoder had assigned to each of these values in each column. So it will probably look like

```
[0,0,0,0]
```

However, you should note that the docs mention "This transformer should be used to encode target values, i.e. y, and not the input X."
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html

So you may want to use onehotencoder https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder

Answer (score 1):

You need to know what the mapping from categories to encodings is, in order to apply to new data.  When you use the same `lencoder` object in the second line:

```py
w['humidity'] = lencoder.fit_transform(w['humidity'])
w['outlook'] = lencoder.fit_transform(w['outlook'])
```

you (and python) have completely forgotten what that mapping is for the `humidity` column, by refitting the same encoder.

You could set up separate encoders then, and then just use `.transform` on your test data.  However, that's not the real solution.  [As Nohman says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72583133/10495893), `LabelEncoder` is meant for *labels*, i.e. target values; the better solution is to use `OrdinalEncoder`, which has roughly the same effect, but can be applied to a 2D array, encoding each column separately.  So:

```py
oencoder = preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder()
cat_cols = ['humidity', 'outlook', 'temperature', 'windy']
w[cat_cols] = oencoder.fit_transform(w[cat_cols])
...

# I don't know what other columns you have, so I can't make this completely faithful:
test = [['sunny', 'hot', 'high', 'false']]
test_enc = oencoder.transform(test)
model.predict(test_enc)
```

You can make this even nicer, using `Pipeline` and (if you have non-categorical columns) `ColumnTransformer`.

Finally, a bit of advice given your example: the categorical features you have might well have an implicit order to them.  You can specify the order to encode in `OrdinalEncoder`, which is likely to produce better results than encoding them in the default order (alphabetical).